# golang binaryTree Preorder return value not right

Tags: go, data-structures, binary-tree

I want to return the values of all nodes as an array, but the return value is wrong.

```
type TreeNode struct {
    Left  *TreeNode
    Right *TreeNode
    Val   int
}

type BinaryTree struct {
    Root *TreeNode
}
    func PreorderRecursion(root *TreeNode, result []int) []int {
    if root == nil {
        return nil
    }
    result = append(result, root.Val)
    res1 :=PreorderRecursion(root.Left,result)
    res2 :=PreorderRecursion(root.Right,result)
    result = append(result,res1...)
    result = append(result,res2...)
    return result
}

func TestBinaryTree_PreOrder(t *testing.T) {
    tree := BinaryTree{}
    tree.Root = &TreeNode{Val: 1}
    tree.Root.Left = &TreeNode{Val: 2}
    tree.Root.Right = &TreeNode{Val: 3}

    tree.Root.Left.Left = &TreeNode{Val: 4}
    var result []int
    result =PreorderRecursion(tree.Root,result)
    fmt.Println(result,"----")
}
```

right result should be : 1 2 4 3

but i get this:[1 1 2 1 2 4 1 3]

Comment: [Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs, Niklaus Wirth.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs) You provided your algorithms. Where are your data structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Slices hold references to an underlying array, and if you assign one
>   slice to another, both refer to the same array. If a function takes a
>   slice argument, changes it makes to the elements of the slice will be
>   visible to the caller

see slices in Effective Go [Slices](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices)

**PreorderRecursion** shouldn't take in a slice and change it. Here's an approach.

```
func PreorderRecursion(root *TreeNode) []int {
    if root == nil {
        return nil
    }
    result := append([]int{}, root.Val)
    res1 := PreorderRecursion(root.Left)
    res2 := PreorderRecursion(root.Right)
    result = append(result, res1...)
    result = append(result, res2...)
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from you passing the `result` slice to the recursive calls. Because of this, each recursive call is going to append the results from the node above. You expect `1 2 4 3`, but you get `1` from the first call, then `1 2` (instead of just `2`) from the second call, then `1 2 4` (instead of just `4`) from the third call.

To fix this you can just remove passing the result slice to the recursive function. The function should only be creating a result slice for the node it's on plus it's descendant trees, it should not need to know what the results from the parent are.